# Eigenvalues of product of two vectors and circulant matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, circulant-matrices

I have the following matrix:

$$A_{ij} = B_{ij} C_{ij} = v_i v_j C_{ij}$$

where $v$ is a vector of wavenumbers and $C$ is a circulant matrix. I want to find the eigenvalues/vectors of $A$. The matrix $B$ is of rank 1 with eigenvalue $\lambda^B = \sum_i v_i^2$, and the eigenvalues/vectors of $C$ are given by the (inverse) Fourier transform (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix#Other_properties)).

Is there any way of relating the eigenvalues/vectors of $A$ to those of $B$ and $C$, in this particular case?

Answer (score 1):

Now
$$
A = DCD
$$
where $D = diag(v_1\dots v_n)$. I have no idea how to get the eigenvalues of $A$ from those of $C$.

[Answer for first version of question] The matrix $A$ satisfies
$$
A = v v^TC.
$$
It has rank at most $1$, thus minimum $n-1$ zero eigenvalues. If $v^TC=0$, then $A=0$. If $v^TCv=0$ then $A^2=0$, and $A$ is nilpotent and has no non-zero eigenvalues.
If $v^TCv\ne0$, then this value is an eigenvalue to the eigenvector $v$:
$$
Av = vv^TCv = (v^TCv) v.
$$

Comment: Apologies, I messed up the index notation in my original answer. I have fixed this now. Does this change your answer?